# python 3.5 32 bit windows import module fails but pip install worked

Tags: python, python-3.x

new to python installed python 3.5 32-bit on windows 10, used pip to install a module

```
C:\Users\Lopez\Anaconda3\Scripts>pip install ystockquote
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ystockquote in c:\users\lopez\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

when I go to the IDLE and try the following I get a no module name

> > > import ystockquote
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >           import ystockquote
> > >       ImportError: No module named 'ystockquote'

not sure what i am missing, guess its path related but appreciate any feedback
thanks, Juan

Comment: `ystockquote` is already installed (says the 2d line). Probably you're running an interpreter (IDLE) whose version is different from the one of the library you've installed. I don't know how it is in Windows, but in linux `pip` matches the 2.7 libraries and `pip3` is to be used to install python3 libraries. If it's the same in Windows, then no wonder you can't import the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help guys,
I beleive the issues where with adding paths to my environment variables not the version of pip. I managed to get this working using the window pip install once i installed python 3 in a custom directory C:\Python35 rather than the deafault long windows suggested path

**Instructions**
In the Control Panel, search for Environment; click Edit the System Environment Variables. Then click the Environment Variables button.
In the User Variables section, we will need to either edit an existing PATH variable or create one. If you are creating one, make PATH the variable name and add the following directories to the variable values section as shown, separated by a semicolon. If you’re editing an existing PATH, the values are presented on separate lines in the edit dialog. Click New and add one directory per line.
C:\Python35-32;C:\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\;C:\Python35-32\Scripts\

Answer (score 0):

Run `pip --version` and check the Python version and start IDLE and check the Python version and see if they match.

If not, use explicit `pipx.y` matching IDLE or start IDLE from a Python matching plain `pip`.