# Requests is installed but still no module found error comes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have installed the python in path: C:\Python\Python35-32

I have successfully installed Requests module:
[image]

But when I try to import - I receive the error as not found.
[image]

Could you please guide me where I wrong -  I am a beginner and using Idle in Windows.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346472/when-a-python-module-cairo-is-installed-successfully-but-fails-to-import-in-py) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37593483/python-3-5-32-bit-windows-import-module-fails-but-pip-install-worked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is case sensitive. Use `import requests`.

Comment: Thank you. I think down rating should be given to this website: https://first-web-scraper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Not really. The website snippets further down use `import requests`, `Requests` is only used with `pip install Requests` because `pip install` commands are _not_ case sensitive, unlike imports.

Comment: Thank you, corrected my mistake.